# Python3 string encode confusing output

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm using python3,and I don't know what happened here:

```
x=[0xc2,0x50]
print('----list2bytes------')
for i in bytes(x):
  print(i)

s=''
for i in x:
  s+=chr(i)

print('----string2bytes----')
for i in s.encode():
  print(i)

print('----string2ord------')
for i in s:
  print(ord(i))
```

----list2bytes------
194
80
----string2bytes----
195
130
80
----string2ord------
194
80

Why did bytes change after string.encode()?

Comment: It seems you think that `encode` is just something like `.toByteArray()`. Please read a bit about it: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode.

Comment: Side note: It's a really bad idea to use `str` as a variable name since it's also a type.

Comment: yes,now I know python3 built-in encoding in windows is unicode,when unicode transfer to utf-8,then 194(unicode/ascii) change to C3 82(uft-8),and never transfer binary file to sring.

Comment: @chengxuncc: you may want to change this comment into an answer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different concepts involved here:

- The `chr()` function will give you the `character` at the specified [`Unicode Code Point`](https://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point). You can look-up Code Point 194 [here](https://altcodeunicode.com/unicode-character-lookup-table/), it's `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX` (no surprises there).
- Adding a character to a string will add that character, not a raw byte to that string. Getting bytes back involves an encoding.
- When you call `.encode()` on the string, you get the bytes of it's `UTF-8`-encoding back. This is not just a concatenation of Code Points.
- The UTF-8 encoding for the character `Â` has two bytes because it's Ucode-value is greater than 128. The first byte is `192 + (Ucode-value div 64)` == `192 + (194 div 64)`, which is `194` == `0xc2` again (adding to the confusion). The second byte is `128 + (Ucode-value div 64)` == `128 + (194 % 64)` == `0x82`.

  Hence the character `Â` encodes to `0xc2, 0x82` in UTF-8.

  The second character's (`P`) Ucode-value is below 128, so it's just added. Thereforce `0xc2, 0x82, 0x50` == `194, 130, 80` is the entire string encoded to UTF-8.

  It is entirely coincidental that the Code Point sequence `194, 80` encodes as `194, 130, 80` in UTF-8, giving the impression that `130` was simply inserted.
- Calling `ord()` will give you Unicode Code Points for each character again. The integer representation of the Unicode Code Point for character `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX` is 194.